# Serving AWS S3 images from a URL on my site's main domain

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Is it possible to serve AWS S3 images from a URL on my site's main domain?

My site is an Express app running on a URL like https://example.com. I'm using AWS S3 to host my site's images. But instead of using the raw S3 URL, I'd like to use a URL that's on my main domain like this:

https://example.com/image/imagename.jpg

Most of the articles I've read involving using a CNAME record for a subdomain, or hosting your entire site on S3, neither of which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using AWS Cloudfront and AWS Route 53 to create a DNS record in conjunct with AWS S3.

Here i attach a tutorial to do it:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-amazon-s3-as-a-content-delivery-network/

https://reidweb.com/2017/02/06/cloudfront-cdn-tutorial/

https://adefy.com/2016/04/25/setting-up-amazon-s3-cloudfront-route53/

If you have a doub,you can tell me the problem and i can help you because the tutorial is old.

Comment: For dynamic content you can create a function with the AWS API  to upload the content to your S3 bucket and consume the resources by the cdn url, for example https://cdn.example.com/image/imagename.jpg

Comment: These instructions are for setting up a CDN on a subdomain. How can I serve the images from my main domain? I want to serve images from https://example.com/image/imagename.jpg, not from https://cdn.example.com/imagename.jpg

Comment: @BrayanCaldera answers here should be self-contained, not references to off-site links.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood is you want a url like:

https://example.com/image/imagename.jpg

and don't want to use S3 to host your website then in this case you can create a bucket policy `s3:GetObject` Permission with a condition using the `AWS:refer` key that tells that GetObject request must be from specific website.

Here is the sample bucket policy:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For more information you can read [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)

Comment: Thanks. I'm more interested how to set up the image URL itself, not where the request comes from. I'd like the image URL to be https://example.com/image/imagename.jpg, but I don't need to restrict where the request comes from.